# What does this line mean ' Verify the new disk in the Guest OS (Ubuntu through GUI and Terminal) '

Tags: linux

I'm new to this but please can anyone tell me what does this mean:
**•  Verify the new disk in the Guest OS (Ubuntu through GUI and Terminal)**
I have completed the first step of creating a new disk but don't know what this specifically means.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux systems. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.